# Unable to set default value for dropdown in Angular Material

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, dropdown

I am using `mat-select` within Angular Material as below:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
   <mat-select (selectionChange)="dropdownSelectedItem($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of itemList" [value]="item">
      {{item.name}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The above dropdown is coming up fine but the dropdown has no default value.

In order to add a default value, I have added `value="{{dropdownSelectedName}}"` as below:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
   <mat-select (selectionChange)="dropdownSelectedItem($event)" value="{{dropdownSelectedName}}">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of itemList" [value]="item">
      {{item.name}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The above change is still not populating the default dropdown value.

I have also tried doing `[(value)]="dropdownSelectedName"`

When I do `console.log(this.dropdownSelectedName)` in the component, I can see that it has a string value
`mydefaultvalue`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subs.sink = this.myService.listAll()
        .subscribe(r => {
            this.AllList = r;
        });
    this.dropdownSelectedName = "mydefaultvalue";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a default value to `mat-select`, you have to bind `compareWith` property, which will compare the values and will set the default value.

Example:

In your HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
   <mat-select (selectionChange)="dropdownSelectedItem($event)" [(ngModel)]="dropdownSelectedName" [compareWith]="compareFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of itemList" [value]="item">
      {{item.name}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your TS:

```
compareFn(obj1: any, obj2: any) {
    return obj1 && obj2 ? obj1.id === obj2.id : obj1 === obj2;
}
```

Comment: it is working fine exactly as expected. thanks. can you please help me understand what `return obj1 && obj2 ? obj1.id === obj2.id : obj1 === obj2` is doing? it is always returning `false` in my case

Comment: Basically, when we try to set some predefined value to mat-select, it will not work directly because of some reference issue, so it unable to set the value. `compareFn` function that tells Angular how to compare the values.
See when you debug that `compareFn`, it will check list of items as obj1 and you value as obj2, and it will run until the condition gets true. If match found then it will set that value.

Answer (score 1):

- the value of your `mat-option` is a object reference to a `item` Object.
- therefore the value that you set on `mat-select` must be the exact same `item` object reference.

this means that in your compoenent your code should

```
this.dropdownSelectedName = [Insert Object Reference Here]
```

the alternative approach is to change your `mat-option` to set

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of itemList" [value]="item.name">
  {{item.name}}
<mat-option>
```

with this change your "myDefaultValue" would match the value of one of the options, instead of being an object reference

**Update**

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-l4dccc?file=src/app/app.component.html) is a link that shows a working version of setting the value of the select when using object references.

Comment: but this doesn't answer my question. I want to populate value of dropdown to the string `mydefaultvalue` whenver user opens it for the first time. This value is different than the values from within `itemList`

Comment: because you are setting the `mat-option` values as an object reference. your `dropdownSelectedName` needs to set the value to the same object reference. once you do that angular will find the mat-option with a matching object reference.  
In my response the line where is states `[Insert Object Reference Here]`. instead of passing a string. find the find the `item` object reference you want to set as the default value, and use that as the default value. instead of a string

Comment: when i do `this.dropdownSelectedName = [Insert Object Reference Here]` it is still not populating the default value to `mydefaultvalue`

Comment: I have update the answer with a link to a working version in stackblitz